# Echo keystrokes including whitespace

Tags: java, echo, inputstream, bufferedreader, jtextarea

**How can I echo each keystroke from a JTextArea, so that even if the user enters onto a new line, types something equal to NULL (e.g. an indentation) and carries on typing, all the keystrokes are echoed?**

I'm trying to use a `BufferedReader` with `readLine()` in order to return an echo for every keystroke pressed, but I want it to continue echoing once I move on to a new line.

What I'm trying to do is to echo any text in `JTextArea1`, to `JTextArea2` and to maintain all the lines, spaces and indentation.

e.g. when typing the following in `JTextArea1`, it should be echoed into `JTextArea2` with all the `whitespaces` and `indentation` etc

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 1;
    }
```

**This is what my echo server is currently doing:**

```
    while (true) {

        Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
        System.out.println("connection accepted");
        ServerOut = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream(),
                true);
        ServerIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                clientSocket.getInputStream()));

        String inputLine;
        if ((inputLine = ServerIn.readLine()) != null) {

            ServerOut.println(inputLine);
        }
        else {

        }

    }
```

My client class, uses `textArea1.getText()` to send the text to server, and uses `textArea2.setText(brIn.readLine().toString())` to append the echoed text.

The else statement is to deal with the `null` case i.e. when pressing enter for a new line, but I'm not sure yet how to hand code it....

Your advices would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a specific problem or a specific question?

Comment: Hi VGR, I've updated the question at the top of the post. I'm trying to be more specific.

Comment: The first line of text echoes just fine, however the problem is when I press enter and move onto a new line in the JTextArea. I guess because the line is equal to null, the code fails. I'm struggling to come up with something that continues to echo if the line is initially null, but the user may continue typing on the new line later.

Comment: Split the problem: (1) Swing JTextArea to System.out.println, and (2) a list of lines from client to server.

Comment: Thanks Joop Eggen... I'm quite new to this so I'm not sure what you mean. I would be grateful if you could elaborate.

Comment: Alternatively, on the server side, I was considering using a Scanner object to read input

Comment: The problem is not about BufferedReader versus Scanner.  You should call clientSocket.getInputStream and clientSocket.getOutputStream only once, and then start your `while` loop after obtaining those streams.

Comment: VGR, I have tried as you've suggested, however after the first key is echoed, the connection fails.... all I have now within my while loop is:

while (true) {

   

   String inputLine;
   if ((inputLine = ServerIn.readLine()) != null) {
    
    ServerOut.println("server" + inputLine);
   }
   else {
   }

  }